# Apollo-Server display errors in a clean mannor

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, apollo, apollo-server

I'm pretty sure that the question is self explanatory.
I'm using 'apollo-server-core' 3.6.5

Errors I want to get

```
 {
      "errors": [
        {
          "message": "Syntax Error: Unexpected <EOF>.",
          "locations": [
            {
              "line": 1,
              "column": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Errors I do get

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "GraphQL operations must contain a non-empty `query` or a `persistedQuery` extension.",
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "stacktrace": [
            "GraphQLError: GraphQL operations must contain a non-empty `query` or a `persistedQuery` extension.",
            "    at processGraphQLRequest (C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Documents\\Github\\XXXX-XXX\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\src\\requestPipeline.ts:204:7)",
            "    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)",
            "    at async processHTTPRequest (C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Documents\\Github\\XXXX-XXXX\\node_modules\\apollo-server-core\\src\\runHttpQuery.ts:346:24)"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My initial thought was parse the error into an object, and map out any undesirables like so

```
 const msg = JSON.parse(error.message).errors.map((err:any) => err = {message: err.message});
```

But that dose not work as it dose not tell you where the mistake occurred + it seems unnecessary to use JSON.parse and then stringify'ing it right back.

Comment: Welcom to StackOverflow! did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Hey @pmk, no I haven't found a solution yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apollo docs cover error handling.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/#throwing-errors

You can create a custom error like this:

```
import { ApolloError } from 'apollo-server-errors';

throw new ApolloError('My error message', 'MY_ERROR_CODE', myCustomExtensions);
```